# What is the performance impact of pg_stat_statements?

Tags: postgresql, pg-stat-statements

I am using `pg_stat_statements` to find the slow queries in my production PostgreSQL 13. Two things:

- I am unsure of the performance impact of this extension.
- Is there anything I can do to improve its performance?  The query below takes > 1s - any suggestions?

```
    -- add the plugin 
    create extension pg_stat_statements;
    select pg_stat_reset();
    select pg_stat_statements_reset();
```

and then:

```
-- find slow queries using the extension:

select * from pg_stat_statements order by total_exec_time desc limit 50;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [here](https://pganalyze.com/faq):

> - What are the performance implications of pganalyze?
>
> The performance overhead of the pg_stat_statements extension is small
>
> - it requires a bit of additional shared memory and will consume about ~1% of CPU time.

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54937806/470530) is a quote from a PostgreSQL contributor who says:

> I always enable it on production databases. The benefits are well
> worth the small performance hit.
>
> Particularly on a production database you want to know which
> statements cause the most pain and should be optimized.

From [here](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2019/02/08/the-most-useful-postgres-extension-pg-stat-statements/) (another big hitter in the PostgreSQL field):

> If you use Postgres and you haven’t yet used pg_stat_statements, it is
> a must to add it to your toolbox.

[This](http://pgsnaga.blogspot.com/2011/10/performance-impact-of-pgstatstatements.html) is old - two separate results:

> With enabling pg_stat_statements module, the pgbench score was 468.2
> tps. And without (loading) the pg_stat_statements module, pgbench
> score was 470.3 tps. The difference (overhead) was just 0.5%

```
     - Shared Buffers : 2048MB
     - Checkpoint Segments : 32
     - WAL Buffers : 1024kB
     - Pgbench: Scale factor 10, 1,000 Transactions * 32 Clients
```

Under certain (specialised IMHO) conditions, he found that there was a 10% peformance impact.

It strikes me that the first test was a much more "server-like" scenario.

### Overall:

The fact that **all** of the bigger players in the PostgreSQL sphere (highly) recommend it **and** the fact that there are no queries either here or on StackOverflow (that I could find) of the sort: `"I enabled pg_stat_statements" and now my server is running slowly"`, appears to augur well for the tool on that score.

Having said all of the above, there can be **no substitute** for benchmarking on your own system with your hardware, software and networking configuration. Initially, you could try switching it on and off during quiet times - but bear in mind that doing this requires a server restart!